# Image overlapping Div when VH is added

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to set up div sections so they take up about 95vh of the web page.

The issue is that when I add vh to one of the sections, the image on the next section overlaps the previous section blocking off some of the content.

All of the divs have relative positioning and this only occurs when I add a vh to the div.

[image]

```
section#showcase{
    height:92vh;
}
#contentShowcase{
    height:92vh;
}
section#judging {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 90vh;

}
section#judging #contentEnter {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height:350px;
}
#judgingImg {
    background: url('../images/beyond-2015-city.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
    height:50vh;

}
/* Section Content */
section#mainContent, 
section#mainContentEnter, 
section#mainContentAttend, 
section#gobeyond, 
section#event, 
section#eventInfo, 
section#enter, 
section#attend, 
section#judging, 
section#sponsors, 
section#venue, 
section#showcase,
section#form,
#eventQuote, 
#judgingImg, 
#sponsorsImg, 
.contentBlock {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#scrolltoBeyond2015, #scrolltoEvent, #scrolltoShowcase, #scrolltoJudging, #scrolltoVenue {
    padding-top: 68px;
    margin-top: -68px;
    display:block;
}





 <section id="showcase" class="">
                <a id="scrolltoShowcase"></a>    
                <div class="chevronDown chevDkBlue hidden-lg hidden-md"></div>

                <div id="contentShowcase" class="row col-DarkBlue bkgrd-LtAccentBlue">
</div>
</div>
</section>
  <section id="judging">
            <a id="scrolltoJudging"></a>
            <a class="chevronDown chevtntBlue" href="#scrolltoJudging"></a>
            <div id="judgingImg"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: might be resolved using `z-index`

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Z-index would just cause the showcase to overlap the image, it's an issue with the relative positioning not working correctly but I can't for the life of my understand why relative isn't working when VH is added.

Comment: can you provide your html??

Comment: I provided the html but I don't think it's going to add much insight to this.

Comment: HTML does not have any content and therefore is quite difficult to get what you're trying to achieve in here. It also has an additional </div> ending which might cause some issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `z-index` to set things right in a kind of a layering style.

```
section#showcase {
   height: 92vh;
   z-index: 100;
}
#contentShowcase {
   height: 92vh;
   z-index: 80;
}
```

In this case, `section#showcase` would be at the top of the `#contentShowcase` for it has the higher value of z-index.

Comment: that will not solve the issue because the columns _WILL STILL OVERLAP_, no matter the 1st one on the 2nd or vice versa

Comment: The issue isn't with what appears above / below but the relative positioning not having any affect when VH height is added.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with both CSS and HTML included? Would help us solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code the problem was caused due to this css -

```
#contentShowcase{
    height:92vh;
}
```

you will see that the `div#contentShowcase` is inside `section` on which you have set `height: 92vh` but when you set `height: 92vh` on the child div `#contentShowcase`, this div goes out of the boundaries of `section` and hence the part of this `div` is below the next `section`

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpbfnwfd/) with your original code, I have added a green border to illustrate how it goes out of `section`
now [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpbfnwfd/1/) in which I have removed `height`

so stop setting `height` in `vh` in `div` present inside `section` in which too you have set `height` in `vh`, use `%` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that should work but it's still having no luck on development. I'll keep poking around.

Comment: @Alex then I think something else might be also causing problem, you need to provide more code or it will be best if you can create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net, when you will make start copying small piece of code and then go pasting codes until the jsfiddle show the same behavior, by doing this you can yourself find the problem in the code which is causing problem.

Comment: this is all the code that sits on this page unfortunately. I was able to get it to work by removing the VH from the section#showcase and adding it to the content, this then breaks when you get down to 992px which is leading me to believe that bootstrap has been causing the issue for some reason or another.